# Display caret position in textfield in Firefox or resize textfield as needed

Tags: jquery, firefox, textbox, mozilla, maskedtextbox

There is an annoying bug in Firefox which allows me to set the caret position in a textfield, but it does not automatically scroll that caret into view.

My particular issue arises when using the jQuery Masked Input Plugin (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

If the width of the textfield is less than the width of the input, you cannot see what you are typing. I need a way to fix this or to force the textbox to grow.

Here's some example code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($){
   $('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999? ext:99999');
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" width="10">
```

Comment: Btw. Umm there is no attribute width for the input tag. Do you mean size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already been said, but you might try setting the size attribute of the input element either statically or dynamically.